# aod255 netbook wireless connection legitimation problem

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, atheros, aspire-one

Following problem:
I tried to install ubuntu 14.04 lts on an Acer Aspire One D255 because the pre-installed windows 7 starter was running annoyingly slow. ubuntu is way faster, but now I got a new problem: I can't connect to the wireless lan. Everytime I try ubuntu asks me for the legitimation. When I type in the WPA2 passphrase it looks like it would try to connect, but only a few seconds later it asks me again for the key. How can I connect anyway to the wireless lan? Google wasn't very helpful in this topic..

Further information:

- The ethernet runs just fine.
- The wireless adapter is: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285
- The kernel driver in use is: ath9k
- I am are using the router Speedport w 724v
- WiCD doesn't work either.
- I have checked if the passphrase is correct. Five times.
- I'm a complete linux noob, please be gentle.

If you need more information please tell me. Could you please help me in this issue?
Best regards, HankJW.

Answer (score 0):

Mine answer is only a workaround. I often encounter these kinds of WiFi problems and as long as they are not solved I use a small and cheap and fully functional WiFi dongle...

And sometimes it is just a bad antenna which makes the connection break down.